# Highlight text with gray box

Tags: margins, highlighting, box

How can I achieve the same gray box as in the below image? In particular there should be no internal padding and it should not break indentation when starting a new paragraph (cf. the indent of DEFINITION in the image). Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us a short compilable TeX code ...

Comment: @Mensch Unfortunately I don't have the tex code of the above image (else I wouldn't be asking). I didn't really try anything yet since I have never worked with something comparable.

Comment: With the existing comments below, I think you need to provide your MWE and more details about what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The `\colorbox` should start with a `\noindent` if there are some default indentation, and better the width of the box should be equal to `\linewidth`, so it can be used also in narrow spaces, such inside a list. The indentation and paragraph skips is reset inside a `minipage` or a `\parbox`, so the easiest fix is just manually `\setlength` the `\parskip` and the `\parindent` inside each box, because the parent indentation could change depending on the environment of the document (e.g., inside lists). Set automatically both lengths for  every possible environment could be tricky. The example show a macro that take the correct indentation and paragraph inside the  main text and a `itemize` list only. No guarantee that it will work elsewhere:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parindent 3em  % some clear but dirty indentation and paragraph skip  
\parskip 2em plus 1em minus 1em

\newlength{\currentparindent}\currentparindent\parindent % remember the global indentation
\newlength{\currentparskip}\currentparskip\parskip % remember the global skips


\makeatletter
\newcommand\graybox[1]{%
\noindent % no intented box !!
\colorbox{gray!20}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\def\insideitemize{itemize}
 \ifx\@currenvir\insideitemize  
        \parskip 4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt % like itemsep
  \else
        \parindent\currentparindent % use the global indentation
        \parskip\currentparskip  % use the global paragrapk skip

\fi  #1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2][1-2]\par \lipsum[3][1-2] % normal dummy paragraphs

\graybox{\lipsum[2][1-2]\par \lipsum[3][1-2]} % now boxed

\lipsum[5][1-2]
\newpage % now in nested list
\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[2][1-2] \par \lipsum[3][1-2]
    \item \graybox{\lipsum[2][1-2]\par \lipsum[3][1-2]}
    \item \lipsum[5][1-2]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[2][1-2] \par \lipsum[3][1-2]
    \item \graybox{\lipsum[2][1-2]\par \lipsum[3][1-2]}
    \item \lipsum[5][1-2]
\end{itemize}   
\end{itemize}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want. Please provides more details and an MWE.

Here is just an example based on my guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{gray!30}{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\setlength\parindent{24pt} some text you want with indentation;\\
some text you want but no indentation.
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't want the indentation of new paragraphs to break, but the minipage environment breaks it...

Comment: @Nicolas when you say 'break', do you mean not indent?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @Nicolas The minipage can still do the indentation if you want. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: yes, but it should do it naturally (i.e. it should adhere to the specification of indentation for theorems and when starting a new paragraph) meaning I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: @Nicolas I believe your 'naturally' request is another question. You may need to solve this question first and then open another one.